# How to get the value of a variable name generated using paste in R

Tags: r

So I have the following code

```
for (n in 1:15) {
    hurst[i]<-get(paste("t$V",n,"$Hs", sep=""))  
    i<-i+1
}
```

With the console printing the error

> Error in get(paste("t$V", n, "$Hs", sep = "")) :  object 't$V1$Hs' not
>   found

I would like to loop over `hurst[i]<-t$Vn$Hs` with the variable on the RHS also changing with each iteration.

Comment: Try to forget `get`. Start with `t[paste0("V",1:15)]` which will give you the sublist of V1, V2,...V15 elements in `t`. Then you can simply use `lapply` on that to extract each `Hs` element from each, something like `lapply(sublist,"[[","Hs")`.

Comment: ```$``` are illegal in object names. I assume that ```t``` is the object and you are trying to use ```$``` notation to extract parts of that object

Comment: Yes indeed, t is the object and I am using $ to extract parts of it.

Comment: Thanks @joran I think this might work.  Let me try it out and get back.

Comment: @joran Thanks. That was the answer itself :) If you don't mind could you explain the second and third argument inside lapply?

Comment: The `[` and `[[` list/vector indexing operators are themselves functions, and so they can be called just like any other function in R. The third argument is an "additional argument" that `lapply` passes on to `[[` to construct what you would normally think of at `my_list[["Hs"]]`. But rephrased with a more function-call like sematics.

Comment: That is pretty neat. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First consider `fortune(312)`:

```
> library(fortunes)
> fortune(312)

The problem here is that the $ notation is a magical shortcut 
and like any other magic if used incorrectly is likely to do 
the programmatic equivalent of turning yourself into a toad.    
-- Greg Snow (in response to a user that wanted to
   access a column whose name is stored in y via x$y
   rather than x[[y]])
   R-help (February 2012)
```

Now look back at where you learned to subset using `$`, if that source did not teach you that `$` is a magical shortcut (or other phrasing) and that sometimes a shortcut is the longest path between 2 points, so use the regular indexing instead of the shortcut, then that person deserves to be hit up side the head with a wet fish.  If they did teach that, then you should apologize to them for not paying attention (and now pay attention).

Also, for assigning to a vector, look at using `sapply` instead of the for loop.  You do not tell us what `t` contains or what `hurst` should be, but here is some sample code that shows an approach without `get`:

```
> t <- lapply(1:15, function(i)list(Hs=i*10))
> names(t) <- paste0('V', 1:15)
> t$Other <- "don't grab me"
> 
> hurst <- sapply( paste0("V", 1:15), 
+                  function(v) t[[c(v,"Hs")]])
> hurst
 V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 
 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120 130 140 
V15 
150 
>
```

Comment: What a lovely answer. Thank you for helping out a toad. I think I was not paying attention. By the way, t is a list of lists and hurst is simply a vector.